# Pygame Rect class

Tags: python, class, pygame, rect

How do I define a rectangular class in Pygame?

```
class square(pygame.Rect)
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.Rect.__init__(self)
```

The code above, which you will use to define a sprite class doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, top_corner, width, height):
        self._x = top_corner[0]
        self._y = top_corner[1]
        self._width = width
        self._height = height

    def get_bottom_right(self):
        d = self._x + self.width
        t = self._y + self.height
        return (d,t)
```

You can use this like this:

```
# Makes a rectangle at (2, 4) with width
# 6 and height 10
rect = new Rectangle((2, 4), 6, 10) 

# Returns (8, 14)
bottom_right = rect.get_bottom_right
```

Also, you could probably save yourself some time by making a Point class

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Comment: Altough this wasn't exactly what i was looking for, it did (almost) solve my problem. 'rect = new Rectangle((2, 4), 6, 10)' is not supported by python, but this could also be a fault of my version of python.